# Universal motor torque measurement

Tags: current, motor, torque, controller

I would like to control AC universal motor (brushed). I would like to know the load torque, but I cannot measure the torque directly. I have to calculate it from motor parameters. Please let me know what parameters I have to measure to calculate the load torque of the motor.
I have seen that the running motor current changes when the motor windings is heating.
What kind of parameters I have to sense:

1. Current
2. Voltage
3. Speed rpm
4. Temoerature
   ?

What about an equation: Torque = Power/Speed (T=P/ω) ? Can I use this relationship to calculate load torque?

Comment: You need other information in the form of a motor label or data sheet that tells you the maximum torque or, just take a guess and have a fire extinguisher handy. If the motor is 2nd hand then all bets are off.

Comment: If you have the voltage, speed and current you can calculate the approximate torque (it won't be perfect because of  power losses). If you know the motor constants it's even easier.

Comment: The universal motor doesn't have a linear characteristics, so any indirect measurements of torque will give you a very bad approximation.

Comment: What about an equation: Torque = Power/Speed (T=P/ω) ? Can I use this relationship to calculate load torque?